# Как сократить код добавления элементов в Swing JFrame?

Tags: java, массивы, swing, jframe, for

Например есть код:

```
JTextArea tWinF1Liga = new JTextArea();
tWinF1Liga.setWrapStyleWord(true);
tWinF1Liga.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
tWinF1Liga.setBounds(182, 162, 36, 41);
p2.add(tWinF1Liga);
```

И мне нужно создать таких 15 штук,а отличие будет лишь в `JTextArea tWinF1Liga = new JTextArea();` на `JTextArea tWinF2Liga = new JTextArea();` , то есть `id` поменялось (только цифра). И строка `p2.add(tWinF1Liga);` на `p3.add(tWinF2Liga);` где я добавляю новый `JTextArea` в другой `JPanel` (`p3`).

Проблема в том, что это часть кода, а таких `JTextArea`, `JButton`.. куда больше. И не хочется копировать весь этот многострочный код и менять цифру в `id` на единицу. Думал попробовать через `for` решить это дело, типа:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    JTextArea tWinF + i + Liga = new JTextArea();
    tWinF + i + Liga.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    tWinF + i + Liga.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
    tWinF + i + Liga.setBounds(182, 162, 36, 41);
    p + i + 1.add(tWinF + i + Liga);
}
```

но я понимаю, что живу не в сказке. Но можно как-нибудь решить эту проблему или придеться все-таки 15 раз комировать и менять эту шнягу? Спасибо.

Comment: все элементы содержат одни и те же данные? Имена переменных принципиальны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете передавать список для инициализации в отдельный метод. А потом добавлять в панель:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class Test {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test test = new Test();
            JTextArea[] textAreas = {new JTextArea(), new JTextArea(), new JTextArea()};
            test.createTextAreas(textAreas);
            System.out.println(textAreas[0]);
        }

        private void createTextAreas(JTextArea... textAreas) {
            int size = textAreas.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                textAreas[i].setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textAreas[i].setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
                textAreas[i].setBounds(182, 162, 36, 41);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, все верно. Единственное, что не  textAreas[0], а textAreas[i] и в форе можно сразу написать: for (int i = 0; i < textAreas.length; i++), не используя строку   int size = textAreas.length;. 

Жаль только, что в моем случае не подошло, поскольку эти textAreas затем используются в другом месте, а теперь о них там не знают, ибо в форе создаются. Видимо придется в ручную. 

За ответ спасибо, поставил как лучший.

Comment: Спасибо, откорректировал i. В Вашем случае, я бы сделал карту с ключом textArea и ее объектом, создал и наполнил бы как нужно, а потом где они используются брал бы их по ключу, типа как переменные, только без объявления. Ключ можно генерировать динамически и брать их так же вычисляя динамически.

Comment: Кстати, нужно обращаться просто через массив, тогда будет работать.